# How to Select First N Key-ordered Values of column within a grouping variable in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, chaining, method-chaining

I have a dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ('A', 'X'),
    ('A', 'X'),
    ('A', 'Y'),
    ('A', 'Z'),
    ('B', 1),
    ('B', 1),
    ('B', 2),
    ('B', 2),
    ('B', 3),
    ('B', 3),
    ('C', 'L-7'),
    ('C', 'L-9'),
    ('C', 'L-9'),
    ('T', 2020),
    ('T', 2020),
    ('T', 2025)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'SEQ'])
print(df)
```

I want to create a key grouping ID and SEQ in order to select the first 2 rows of each different SEQ within each ID Group

For instance the ID A, has 3 distinct keys "A X", "A Y" and "A Z" in the order of the dataset the first two keys are "A X" and "A Y" thus I must select the first two rows (if available) of each thus

"A X", "A X", "A Y" why? because "A Z" is another key.

I've tried using the groupby and head functions, but I couldn't find a way to achieve this specific result. What can I try next?

```
(df
.groupby(['ID','SEQ'])
.head(2)
)
```

This code is returning the original dataset and I wonder if I can solve this problem using method chaining, as it is my preferred style in Pandas.

The final correct output is:

[image]

Comment: Why is ("A","Y") twice in the output?

Comment: Groupby(‘ID’)[‘SEQ’].rank(method='dense') might help you here

Comment: Rank(method=‘dense’) is also worth understanding because of its portability to SQL’s dense_rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of using groupby and then head(2) is on the right track for getting the first 2 rows of each different SEQ within each ID group.

However, the additional requirement is to get only the first 2 unique SEQ groups within each ID. To achieve this, you can:

Create a new column that has the rank of unique SEQ within each ID group.
Use this rank to filter out the data.
Finally, use your original approach to get the first 2 rows of each SEQ within each ID group.
Here's a solution using method chaining:

```
result = (df
          .assign(rank=df.groupby('ID')['SEQ'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='dense')))
          .query('rank <= 2')
          .groupby(['ID', 'SEQ'])
          .head(2)
          .drop(columns=['rank'])
         )

print(result)
```

This should give you the desired output.

Comment: Ryder! Thank you so much for this, thank you for explaining your code and your feedback and thank you for that AWESOME method chaining style thanks a billion! Do you know where is a good resource to learn more about code in method chaining? I just love that and it is the only thing that is making me feel confortable in python

Comment: Pandas documentation [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html#user-guide). Pandas itself has lot of examples in its documentation. Since method chaining is a common paradigm in Pandas, you'll encounter many instances of it while following code snippets in that documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `pd.factorize()` with `groupby()`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['SEQ'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] <= 1)]
```

Output:

```
   ID   SEQ
0   A     X
1   A     X
2   A     Y
4   B     1
5   B     1
6   B     2
7   B     2
10  C   L-7
11  C   L-9
12  C   L-9
13  T  2020
14  T  2020
15  T  2025
```

Comment: As a key-ordered head is expected, an alternative would be `df[df.groupby('ID')['SEQ'].transform(lambda g: g.rank(method='dense')<=2)]` is the input is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: is it a bug that `.rank()` cannot be used on the groupby object without an error? ('<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int').

Comment: I don't know if this is a "bug", but certainly a limitation if you have mixed types. I guess it could work properly if each group has homogeneous types, but that might be tricky to determine in advance. Imagine 1000 groups and only the last one has mixed types, what should it do? fail after a potentially long computation? yield NaNs? You can open a bug or feature request if you want ;)

Comment: This is good to know!

Answer (score 1):

`drop_duplicates` and then use `groupby` to get the `head` of each "ID". Then `merge` with the original DataFrame to keep duplicate rows.

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates().groupby("ID").head(2).merge(df)

   ID   SEQ
0   A     X
1   A     X
2   A     Y
3   B     1
4   B     1
5   B     2
6   B     2
7   C   L-7
8   C   L-9
9   C   L-9
10  T  2020
11  T  2020
12  T  2025
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you have to group by ID only, then select only unique rows (e.g. by using `drop_duplicates`) then you can use `merge` to retrieve those rows:

```
df = df.\
    merge(
        df.\
        drop_duplicates().\
        groupby(["ID"]).\
        head(2),
        on=["ID", "SEQ"],
        how="right"
    )

df
Out[16]: 
   ID   SEQ
0   A     X
1   A     X
2   A     Y
3   B     1
4   B     1
5   B     2
6   B     2
7   C   L-7
8   C   L-9
9   C   L-9
10  T  2020
11  T  2020
12  T  2025
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
out = df.groupby("ID", group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x[x["SEQ"].isin(x["SEQ"].unique()[:2])]
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   ID   SEQ
0   A     X
1   A     X
2   A     Y
4   B     1
5   B     1
6   B     2
7   B     2
10  C   L-7
11  C   L-9
12  C   L-9
13  T  2020
14  T  2020
15  T  2025
```

Comment: Hey Andrej! THANKS SO MUCH MY MAN! I have  a question! doesnt .apply() slows down pandas? where can I find reference on how to use it propeortly?

Comment: @R_Student Generally, it's advised to avoid `.apply` in pandas if other solution is available. But, as always, it *"depends"*. Mainly on what you do inside the `.apply`. There are situations when you cannot avoid `.apply`, or, when using `.apply` leads to more straightforward code (and the performance is enough)